# Por que não aparece o valor 1 da array no explode?

Tags: php

Quando crio o código:

```
$urlAtual = "https://www.meusite.com.br/customer/account/create/";
$parteurl = explode('/', $urlAtual);
    for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++){
        $parteurldesejada = $parteurl[$i] . "<br>";
        echo $parteurldesejada;
    }
```

Ele imprime no navegador isso:

```
https:

www.meusite.com.br
customer
account
create
```

Veja que o valor `[1]` da array, não é mostrado. Por que?

Codigo fonte fica assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Lucas Carvalho</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
    https:<br><br>www.meusite.com.br<br>customer<br>account<br>create<br><br></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É porque você está dando `explode` pelo `/` e no `//` ele reconhece que entre eles há um valor vazio.

Aparentemente, o que precisa fazer pode ser feito com a função [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url)

```
$urlAtual = "https://www.meusite.com.br/customer/account/create/";
var_dump(parse_url($urlAtual));
```

Comment: Entendi, eu teria que fazer como então? Saberia me dizer? Sem ser pelo /

Comment: Depende de qual a finalidade. O que você quer fazer?

Comment: Preciso pegar TODOS, no caso. Até o // ali.

Comment: Faz um if e imprime um `//` quando estiver na posição 1 do vetor.

Comment: Basta usar o parse_url que é uma funç]ão adequada para isso. @LucasCarvalho

Comment: Vou pesquisar Daniel, obrigado!

Comment: editei na resposta dele ao invés de criar nova resposta.

Comment: De qualquer forma o `parse_url` não vai imprimir o `//` que é o que você quer.

Comment: creio que o `//` é indiferente.. uma vez pegando as partes corretamente, o que é feito no parse_url()

Comment: Mas dessa forma ele vai ter que dar um `explode` no `path` pra conseguir o que aparentemente ele quer.

Answer (score 3):

No próprio [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php#111419) tem um exemplo semelhante ao que você faz. Ele reconhece uma `/` após a `/` e imprime vazio